# Empty Array Back from PostMan POST in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to post data to an API that takes in the following data:

```
{
  "orderID": 0,
  "identifier": "string",
  "customer": "string",
  "items": [
    {
      "productId": 0,
      "quantity": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried POSTING data like this:

```
{
    "orderID": 1,
    "identifier": "mostNewestCustomerIn2021",
    "customer": " John Appleseed ",
    "items": [
        {
            "productId": 2021,
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But all I got back in response was this:

```
{
   {
        "orderID": 1,
        "identifier": "mostNewestCustomerIn2021",
        "customer": " John Appleseed ",
        "items": []
    }
}
```

And the same goes for the GET Method when I try to get the items, it's showing the same response.

And when I looked at my table in SQL it didn't even show an items array:

[image: SQL Table]

And this is what my model looks like:

```
public class OrderLine
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }

        public string Customer { get; set; }

        public OrderLine(string identifier)
        {
            Identifier = identifier;
        }
        public IEnumerable<BasketEntryDto> Items { get; set; } = new List<BasketEntryDto>();
    }
```

And this is my BasketEntryDto I'm making an IEnumerable from in the above class:

```
[Keyless]
    [NotMapped]
    public class BasketEntryDto
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Everything works with the API except for that the "items" sent in with POST does not show up in a response back or in GET or in the SQL Table Data. Why is it not working? Thanks for any help in advance

EDIT:
Here is how I post to my API:

```
// SLÅ IHOP BASKET OCH ORDER
        [HttpPost("basket/together/{identifier}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrderAndBasket(string identifier)
        {
            // Aggregera data från två servicar, och returnerar patient 
            // samt dennas journal.

            var patientDto = await FetchOrder(identifier);

            if (patientDto == null)
                return NotFound(); // 404 Not Found

            patientDto.Items = await FetchBasketEntries(identifier);

            var journalEntryJson = new StringContent(
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(patientDto),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                Application.Json);

            var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            using var httpResponseMessage =
                await httpClient.PostAsync($"http://localhost:5700/new/post", journalEntryJson);

            return Ok(patientDto); // 200 OK
        }
        // OVANFÖR


[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<OrderDTO>> PostOrderDTO(OrderDTO orderDTO)
        {
            // TODO Contact BasketService (GET /api/Baskets/{identifier} and take out 'items array with objects inside' and post to Order

            //var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            // FETCHING BASKET
            //var items = await FetchBasketEntries(orderDTO.Identifier);
            var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            // Get Basket and Order by ID

            // UP HERE
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderDTO);
            // Want to convert fetched basket to Json
            //var jss = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            //var content1 = new StringContent(jss, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //var patientDto = await GetOrderAndBasket(orderDTO.Identifier);

            //Generate Order(Order, OrderLine)

            // I want to send the fetched basket here with my orderDTO
            _context.OrderDTO.Add(orderDTO);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (OrderDTOExists(orderDTO.Identifier))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            //await httpClient.PutAsync($"https://localhost:5500/api/Basket/{orderDTO.Identifier}", content);

            await httpClient.PostAsync($"http://localhost:5700/api/Orders/basket/together/{orderDTO.Identifier}", content);

            return CreatedAtAction("GetOrderDTO", new { id = orderDTO.Identifier }, orderDTO);
        }
```

EDIT: ADDED FETCHORDER AND FETCHBASKETENTRIES:

```
private async Task<OrderDTO> FetchOrder(string identifier)
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
               HttpMethod.Get,
               $"http://localhost:5700/api/Orders/{identifier}")
            {
                Headers = { { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json" }, }
            };

            var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            using var httpResponseMessage =
                await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            OrderDTO orderDTO = null;

            if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return orderDTO;

            using var contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

            var patientServicePatientDto = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                    <OrderDTO>(contentStream, options);

            orderDTO = new OrderDTO(patientServicePatientDto.Identifier)
            {
                OrderID = patientServicePatientDto.OrderID,
                Identifier = patientServicePatientDto.Identifier,
                Customer = patientServicePatientDto.Customer
            };

            return orderDTO; // 200 OK
        }
```

FetchBasketEntries:

```
// FETCH FROM BASKET BY IDENTIFIER TO POST TO ORDER
        [HttpGet("basket/{identifier}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<BasketEntryDto>> FetchBasketEntries(string identifier)
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
               HttpMethod.Get,
               $"https://localhost:5500/api/Basket/{identifier}")
            {
                Headers = { { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json" }, }
            };

            var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            using var httpResponseMessage =
                await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            var basketEntries = Enumerable.Empty<BasketEntryDto>();

            if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return basketEntries;

            using var contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

            var basketDTO = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                    <BasketDto>(contentStream, options);

            //basketDTO = new NewBasketDTO.ItemDTO
            //{
            //    ProductId = basketDTO.ProductId,
            //    Quantity = basketDTO.Quantity
            //};

            basketEntries = basketDTO.Items.Select(x =>
                new BasketEntryDto
                {
                    ProductId = x.ProductId,
                    Quantity = x.Quantity
                }
            );

            return basketEntries; // 200 OK
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the code of API which returns the response? try changing `IEnumerable<BasketEntryDto>` to `List<BasketEntryDto>`

Comment: @Chetan Absolutely, I'll add it to the question :) Thanks

Comment: Like @Chetan mentioned, try changing `public IEnumerable<BasketEntryDto> Items { get; set; } = new List<BasketEntryDto>();` to -> `public List<BasketEntryDto> Items { get; set; }`. I also don't see a [HttpGet] in your code.

Comment: @stersym My mistake, sorry, they're both post methods but they're getting their data both from FetchOrder(identifier) and FetchBasketEntries(identifier) which are GET Methods :) Thanks for the help, I'll try to see if it works

Comment: @stersym :/ Still doesn't work after changing to List

Comment: Can i see the `FetchOrder()` please?

Comment: @stersym Absolute I'll add it to the question :) Thanks

Comment: I started writing an answer but i need to check first. Try removing the List. In your class try `public BasketEntryDto Items{ get; set; }` instead of `public List<BasketEntryDto> Items { get; set; }`. Let me know if this fixes things.

Comment: @stersym No it didn't work, gave me this error in Postman: "The JSON value could not be converted to AnimimoMicroservices.NewOrderService.Models.DTO.BasketEntryDto. Path: $.items | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 14." Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 2):

I use RestSharp for my REST APIs. I strongly suggest you try it. I'll post an answer that uses this. First you need a class for the response or the request.

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    public BasketEntryDto Items { get; set; }
}

public class BasketEntryDto
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need a List for BasketEntryDto unless you expect something like this:

```
"items": 
[{
        "productId": 1,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "productId": 2,
        "quantity": 3
    }
],
```

The GET Method should be something like:

```
public void GetOrder(string identifier)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient(new Uri("http://localhost:5500/yourpath/" + identifier));
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    IRestResponse resp = client.Execute(request);

    OrderLine Order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp.Content);
}
```

You need RestSharp and Newtonsoft.Json packages to achieve this.
Does this work for you?

**EDIT**
I forgot to share the POST Method.

```
public void PostOrder()
{
    OrderLine Order = new OrderLine();
    BasketEntryDto Basket = new BasketEntryDto();

    Order.OrderID = someValue;
    Order.Identifier = "someValue";
    Order.Customer = "someValue";
    Basket.ProductId = someValue;
    Basket.Quantity = someValue;
    Order.Items = Basket;

    RestClient client = new RestClient(new Uri("http://localhost:5500/yourpath"));
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Order);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    request.AddJsonBody(json);

    IRestResponse resp = client.Execute(request);
}
```